# Sending a message on Viber when someone is offline

Tags: samsung, viber-messenger

I sent a message to a friend who was offline on Viber. However the message isn't coming up from my end as 'sent'. I thought it would at least come up as 'sent' and once they are back online it would say 'delivered'? Now Im not sure if it's gone through to them or not?